# Improve the performance of uitableview creation with many sections from sqlite database

Tags: ios, cocoa, sqlite, uitableview

This is my scenario:

Sqlite database with 30000 products with 800 different brands.

Table product is like this:

```
id | title | brand | other fields
```

Products example:

```
1221 | Product 1 | brand 1 | ...
1222 | Product 2 | brand 2 | ...
1223 | Product 3 | brand 2 | ...
1224 | Product 4 | brand 3 | ...
1225 | Product 5 | brand 3 | ...
1226 | Product 6 | brand 3 | ...
```

I need to create a uiviewtable with all products in different sections. Sections are different brands of products.

I must implements this methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

My idea to solve this problem is as follows (written in pseudocode):

```
NSArray * productList = [databaseManager getProductList]; //array with Product model objects
NSArray * brandsList = [databaseManager getBrandsList];


NSMutableDictionary * dictionaryProductBrands = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:bramdsList.count];


for (NSString *brand in brandsList) {
    NSMutableArray *arrayProductsPerBrands = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (Product *p in productList) {
        if ([p.brand isEqualToString:brand]) {

            [arrayProductsPerBrands addObject:p];
        } 
    }

    [dictionaryProductBrands setValue:arrayProductsPerBrands forKey:brand];

}
```

This solution has a poor performance.

Can I improve the way to generate the tableview with sections with the same database?

Comment: while fetching products use query `select * from productTable GroupBy brand` seems little more logical than yours....

Comment: I need numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath, how I can obtain this values with this select?

Comment: I am saying just to append `group by` to your database query so that u will get a nit data. Rest of your logic will remain same